# ASP.NET 3.5: Master Page stylesheet variablized?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, stylesheet

I'm new to ASP.NET coming from a PHP and ColdFusion background and I have a pretty simple question:

Within my Master Page, how can I make one of my CSS file links a variable, so when the appropriate page (Home for example) comes in, it contains the variable with the correct CSS file to use?

```
    <!-- Custom CSS Files -->
    <link href="<Page Specific CSS Variable>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Would this be the answer? Home.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageStylesheet" runat="server">
    <link href="../../Content/Styles/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

And then in Master Page:

```
<!-- Custom CSS Files -->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageStylesheet" runat="server" />
```

Is that right?

Comment: If each content page has its own CSS file, why not just put the CSS link in the content page, instead of in the master page?

Comment: Because each page that's brought in is the meat of the page... not the header.

Comment: But there is a template section (content area) for the header for just this purpose.

Comment: @Nikki, like I said... I'm new. So I'm trying to find out what these "purposes" are. I edited my question above ^^ ... could that be how this works?

Comment: Yep; I posted an example from one of my little apps. A master page is a template; you define its purpose, really. You can use nested master pages as well.

Comment: @dcolumbus, the answer in your edit would probably be the best way to do it; Brandon's solution would work as well, though is more complex for what you need. (But you can use <%= %> to do server-side code for any other dynamic HTML you may need.)

Comment: Check out my latest edit... that right, Gledolkari?

Comment: @dcolumbus - yes, just make sure that in your master page, that ContentPlaceHolder tag is within the <head> </head> tags.

Comment: Correct. It certainly is. Thank you, guys!

Comment: @dcolumbus ~ accept an answer below please. Preferably one of the ones that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you're help, the answer is within my edits. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add a property to the master page that you can set from each web content form.  So for example:

MasterPage.Master

```
    <!-- Custom CSS Files --> 
    <link href="<%=this.PageSpecificCSSURL%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="../../Content/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
```

MasterPage.Master.cs

```
private string mPageSpecificCSSURL = string.Empty;
public string PageSpecificCSSURL
{
    get
    {
        return mPageSpecificCSSURL;
    }
    set
    {
        mPageSpecificCSSURL = value;
    }
}
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((SiteMaster) this.Master).PageSpecificCSSURL = "mypage.css";
}
```

Comment: All that being said - I think your initial instinct was right - add a separate content area to be filled in by each content page.

Answer (score 1):

Use a content section in the page header in the master page. That's its purpose; for CSS and/or script and whatnot that are specific to a content page. The content will be merged with the content of the master page, resulting in a full head section. All content placeholders can be put pretty much anywhere; title, head, foot, whatever you like, and you can nest master pages. They are just templates; you don't have to restrict yourself to BODY content.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="REO.master.cs" Inherits="REO.REO" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>REO CMS</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="REO.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqueryui-1.8%20jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>


<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddCaseContact.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="REO.AddCaseContact" MasterPageFile="~/REO.Master" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">       
        function showMessage(wTitle, msg) {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .html(msg)
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: wTitle,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 300,
                    buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
                });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```